# Hwo to convert Flux<Item> to List<Item> by blocking

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

**Background**

- I have a legacy application where I need to return a `List<Item>`
- There are many different Service classes each belonging to an `ItemType`.
- Each service class calls a few different `backend APIs` and collects the responses to create a SubType of the `Item`.
  So we can say, each service class implementation returns an `Item`
- All backend API access code is using `WebClient` which returns `Mono` of some type, and I can `zip` all `Mono` within the service to create an `Item`
- The user should be able to look up many different types of items in one call. This requires many backend calls

So for performance sake, I wanted to make this all asynchronous using reactor, so I introduced Spring Reactive code.

**Problem**

If my endpoint had to return `Flux<Item>` then this code work fine,
But this is some service code which is used by other legacy code caller.
So eventually I want to return the `List<Item>` but When I try to convert my `Flux` into the `List` I get an error

```
"message": "block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, 
 which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3",
```

Here is the service, which is calling a few other service classes.

```
Flux<Item> itemFlux = Flux.fromIterable(searchRequestByItemType.entrySet())
                .flatMap(e ->
                        getService(e.getKey()).searchItems(e.getValue()))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

 Mono<List<Item>> listMono = itemFlux
                             .collectList()
                             .block(); //This line throws error
```

Here is what the above service is calling

```
default Flux<Item> searchItems(List<SingleItemSearchRequest> requests) {
         
         return Flux.fromIterable(requests)
                .flatMap(this::searchItem)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    }
```

Here is what a single-item search is which is used by above

```
public Mono<Item> searchItem(SingleItemSearchRequest sisr) {


    return Mono.zip(backendApi.getItemANameApi(sisr.getItemIdentifiers().getItemId()),
                    sisr.isAddXXXDetails()
                    ?backendApi.getItemAXXXApi(sisr.getItemIdentifiers().getItemId())
                    :Mono.empty(),
                    sisr.isAddYYYDetails()
                    ?backendApi.getItemAYYYApi(sisr.getItemIdentifiers().getItemId())
                    :Mono.empty())
            .map(tuple3 -> Item.builder()
                    .name(tuple3.getT1())
                    .xxxDetails(tuple3.getT2())
                    .yyyDetails(tuple3.getT3())
                    .build()
            );
}
```

**Sample project to replicate the problem.**.
https://github.com/mps-learning/spring-reactive-example

**I’m new to spring reactor, feel free to pinpoint ALL errors in the code.**

## **UPDATE**

As per **Patrick Hooijer** Bonus suggestion, updating the `Mono.zip` entries to always contain some default.

```
   @Override
    public Mono<Item> searchItem(SingleItemSearchRequest sisr) {
        System.out.println("\t\tInside " + supportedItem() + " searchItem with thread " + Thread.currentThread().toString());

        //TODO: how to make these XXX YYY calls conditionals In clear way?
        return Mono.zip(getNameDetails(sisr).defaultIfEmpty("Default Name"),
                        getXXXDetails(sisr).defaultIfEmpty("Default XXX Details"),
                        getYYYDetails(sisr).defaultIfEmpty("Default YYY Details"))
                .map(tuple3 -> Item.builder()
                        .name(tuple3.getT1())
                        .xxxDetails(tuple3.getT2())
                        .yyyDetails(tuple3.getT3())
                        .build()
                );
    }
    private Mono<String> getNameDetails(SingleItemSearchRequest sisr) {
        return mockBackendApi.getItemCNameApi(sisr.getItemIdentifiers().getItemId());
    }
    private Mono<String> getYYYDetails(SingleItemSearchRequest sisr) {
        return sisr.isAddYYYDetails()
               ? mockBackendApi.getItemCYYYApi(sisr.getItemIdentifiers().getItemId())
               : Mono.empty();
    }
    private Mono<String> getXXXDetails(SingleItemSearchRequest sisr) {
        return sisr.isAddXXXDetails()
               ? mockBackendApi.getItemCXXXApi(sisr.getItemIdentifiers().getItemId())
               : Mono.empty();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have only `spring-boot-starter-webflux` defined as application dependency, then springbok spin up a `Netty server.

One is not expected to `block()` in a reactive application using a non-blocking server.

However, once we add `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency then even with the presence of `spring-boot-starter-webflux`,  springboot spinup a tomcat server. Which is a thread-per-request model and is expected to have  blocking calls

So to solve my problem, all I had to do above is, to add `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in pom.xml. After that applications is started in `Tomcat`
with timcat `.collectList().block()` works in Controller class to return the `List<Item>`.
Whereas with the `Netty server` I could return only `Flux<Item>` not `List<Item>`, which is expected.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Below answer does not solve the issue, but it contains useful information about Thread switching. It does not work because `.block()` is no problem for non-blocking Schedulers if it's used to switch to synchronous code.

<s>This is because the block operator inherited the `reactor-http-nio-3` Thread from `backendApi.getItemANameApi` (or one of the other calls in Mono.zip), which is non-blocking.</s>

Most operators continue working on the Thread on which the previous operator executed, this is because the Thread is linked to the emitted item. There are two groups of operators where the Thread of the output item differs from the input:

1. `flatMap`, `concatMap`, `zip`, etc: Operators that emit items from other Publishers will keep the Thread link they received from this inner Publisher, not from the input.
2. Time based operators like `delayElements`, `interval`, `buffer(Duration)`, etc. will schedule their tasks on the provided Scheduler, or `Schedulers.parallel()` if none provided. The emitted items will then be linked to the Thread the task was scheduled on.

In your case, `Mono.zip` emits items from `backendApi.getItemANameApi` linked to `reactor-http-nio-3`, which gets propagated downstream, goes outside both the flatMap in `searchItems` and in `itemFlux`, until it reaches your block operator.

You can solve this by placing a `.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`, either in searchItem, searchItems or itemFlux. This will cause the item to switch to a Thread in the provided Scheduler.

**Bonus**: Since you requested to pinpoint errors: Your `Mono.zip` will not work if `sisr.isAddXXXDetails()` is false, as Mono.zip discards any element it could not zip. Since you return a `Mono.empty()` in that case, no items can be zipped and it will return an empty Mono.

Comment: Wow! that's a lot to grasp. I think I understood what you are trying to explain. Regarding the main issue, I tried to put `.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`  one by one at all methods, but I’m still facing the same issue...

Comment: Regarding Mono.zip, could you tell me the best way to make these conditional Calls that I may or may not want to zip. If you take a look at the repo link I shared... this was the exact querstion

Comment: One more question, which is not mentioned in the code either. I’ve some RequestScope variable, reactive code does the thread switch, so thread-locals are lost.  So In a real application, I'm getting an error in my API calls because my request scope variables are not available to construct the request.  How can I preserve them

Comment: @ThrowableException Looking at your repo, I see your return your listRepo in the Spring Webflux endpoint `@PostMapping List<Item> searchItems(@RequestBody ItemsSearchRequest itemsSearchRequest)`, can you try changing the return type to `Mono<List<Item>>` and removing the `.block()`?

Comment: @ThrowableException About your other questions: Your new Mono.zip solution should work if `Item` can handle the default details, otherwise you can work with `Optional`s and use `Optional.ifPresent` to populate your builder. I sadly do not know the answer to your RequestScope question.

Comment: the repo I created is just a dummy project, I tested in this repo project by returning Flux<Item> from api endpoint...and it's working fine without blocking. As I mentioned in my question above....  but in actual commercial code that I’m working on, there I am not allowed to change the  endpoint return type. So I;ve to return the List<Item>.... Let me try convincing the Architect to have Flux<Item> as return, instead of a customer responseEntity

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of propagating the requestScope variables?  I’ve a lot an internal library to call backend API, and that library uses some properties from a RequestScope Object. Spring put all requestScope object in ThreadLocal, but due to reactive thread switch I am unable to access the variable. while researching in internet, I found something  about Context, but unable to find the exact solution